# Rails group_by without multiple database calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, scope, enumerable

I have the following method in my `concern`:

```
  def all_calculated_stats(sport, group = false)
    calculated_stats = Stat.calculated(sport.id, id)
    calculated_stats = calculated_stats.group_by { |stat| stat.stat_type.stat_type_category.name } if group
    return calculated_stats
  end
```

calculated scope:

```
  scope :calculated, ->(sport_id, athlete_id) { joins(:stat_type => :stat_type_category).where('stat_types.calculated = ? AND stat_type_categories.sport_id = ? AND stats.athlete_id = ?', true, sport_id, athlete_id) }
```

When the `group_by` is ran multiple select statements run to obviously group the objects together, is there anyway to avoid doing this while still grouping the objects?

Answer (score 1):

It is only running multiple queries to get information that I suspect you could join in your original query.

```
Stat.calculated(sport.id, id).joins(:stat_type => :stat_type_category)
```

That will load the associated `stat_type` and `stat_type_category` objects.

This is based on a couple of assumptions though.

Firstly that they are both single cardinality associations. I.e. `has_one :stat_type` or `belongs_to :stat_type` - otherwise you'll get too many results coming back from the query.

Secondly that all `Stat` instances that are going to be returned have a `stat_type` with a `stat_type_category`. If they don't then they won't be returned by a query with `joins`.

You might also only want to do the join when you need to group otherwise you'll be running a more complete query than you need. E.g.

```
calculated_stats = Stat.calculated(sport.id, id)
if group
  calculated_stats = calculated_stats.joins(:stat_type => :stat_type_category)
  calculated_stats = calculated_stats.group_by { |stat| stat.stat_type.stat_type_category.name }
end
return calculated_stats
```